# Uninstall "3rd party software"

Tags: 16.04, package-management, uninstall

So I recently reinstalled Ubuntu on my computer and during the installation process, I checked the "Install 3rd party software" box. I was wondering if there was a way to revert it and uninstall all of the packages that came with checking that. From looking online, I realize you can uninstall a package at a time but I am wondering if there is a way to uninstall all of those at once or if I want this effect should I re-install Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That checkbox installs the metapackage `ubuntu-restricted-extras` which also includes the metapackage `ubuntu-restricted-addons`.  To see the full list of what this installs see the following pages:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-restricted-extras
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-restricted-addons

Each of these can be uninstalled independently.

There is no sure-fire way to remove them all at once, if they were added at install time.  You *could* remove the multiverse and restricted repositories, and then remove all newly-obsolete packages - if you are sure you don't need anything else in those repositories.