# Help uninstalling 3rd party software

Tags: software-center, uninstall, vpn, cisco, top

I recently installed Cisco Anyconnect in order to VPN into my university's intranet when off site. This software, however, has gone rouge and is crashing my computer regularly. Here is a top example: 
[image]

vpnagentd is the main process, the java process is linked to it as well. These java processes regularly use up to 80% of my RAM, and change their PID every few seconds. So I can't kill them wack-a-mole style. I want this thing off my computer now!

I have tried using "Ubuntu Software" center. I selected the application and said "remove". No effect. I tried `sudo apt-get remove/purge` on various names "cisco" "annyconnect", but these are not recognized. What I would like to know is:
1) How do I find and remove files associated with Cisco Annyconnect?
2) How do I find and disable any services associated with Cisco Annyconnect? (It launches on startup).

Thank you! Note, this question ([Uninstall "3rd party software"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024115/uninstall-3rd-party-software)) seems to be about 3rd party software option on install.

Comment: How did you install it?  You remove software using the opposite method to how it was installed.  `apt remove` will work for apt/dpkg installs, but is the wrong method if it was a snap, install from source etc. You mention `kill`, but did you try `killall`?

Comment: Pretty sure it was a tarball I used. The link I followed is here: http://www.icts.uct.ac.za/AnyConnect

Comment: Let me try killall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maby this will help you ! :)

https://ask.napier.ac.uk/article.php?id=377

- The procedure for manually uninstalling the AnyConnect client from a Linux or Mac OS X system is the same for both systems. As root, **run the following shell script:  /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh**
  - Typically, you would do this via sudo, as follows:
    $ sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh
  - If you do not use sudo, use a root shell:
    # /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh

Comment: Happy to help! :D